# Webpack: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, webpack, electron, dom-events

I use webpack for module loading. Everything works fine except click events from html.

For example I want to do this;

```
<li id="a" onclick="f(this.id)">lorem</li>
```

but getting this error whenever I click that element:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: f is not defined

The compiled js file (that functions part):

```
    function f(d) {
       console.log(d);
    }
```

then I realized, actually it is in a global webpack function:

```
 function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {
    function f(d) {
       console.log(d);
    }
 }
```

I think that this is the reason of the problem.

How can I fix this?

P.S.: I tried handling event from code, it didn't work either.

Comment: `window.f = f` or use `addEventListener`.

Comment: first one works but typescript flags it as an error: Property 'f' does not exist on type 'Window'. If i can fix it too, it'll be flawless.

Comment: Yeah, TypeScript doesn't like you doing things like that. There might be a way to suppress the error, or it could be easier just to use `addEventListener`.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason it didn't work at first try (same error). I will try it again now.

Comment: @Nuri Did you solve this problem?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357489/calling-webpacked-code-from-outside-html-script-tag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling webpacked code from outside (HTML script tag)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357489/calling-webpacked-code-from-outside-html-script-tag)

Comment: Mixing html and JavaScript is bad style. You should work with event listeners