# How access webpack imported es6 class in html?

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, webpack-dev-server

Hi I'm new to webpack and ES6, Trying to access imported class in html. i have a index.js imported classes in it.

```
import one from './src/one.js';
import two from './src/two.js';
import three from './src/three.js';

export {
    one,
    two,
    three
}
```

in index.html i'm trying to access the class.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    let oneObj = new one();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Getting error "one is not defined". Please help me how can i access the classes in html.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to do this configuring webpack (ex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361312/2043830) but I was unable to make it work.

So instead I use the global window object to store the things that I want to expose to index.html.

For example, in your index.js you could do:

```
window.exported = {one, two, three};
//or window.one = one; window.two = two ... etc
```

Then in your index.html:

```
<script>
let oneObj = new window.exported.one();
//or let oneObj = new window.one(); ... etc
</script>
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an intended use case and therefore requires special handling using [`expose-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/expose-loader/).

---

The idea of a module bundler is to run all JavaScript through it (other than having some code somewhere outside). So when you code with `export {one, two, three}` is in `lib.js`, use it in `app.js`:

```
import {one} from './lib.js';
let oneObj = new one();
```

Configure webpack to use `./app.js` as entry file, and finally remove the inline script from your `index.html`.

Comment: Thanks for response. In app.js I'm able to use the "oneObj" but i want to use oneObj in index.html