# Webpack 2 accessible functions from different js files

Tags: javascript, webpack-2

Just started using webpack-2 and have a question about global functions. Have these functions in js file named `showPictures.js`:

```
function isEmpty(el) {
    var result = !$.trim(el.html());
    return result;
}
function showPicturesList() {
    if (!isEmpty($('#picture-name-list'))) {
        var pictureList = document.getElementById("added-pictures");
        pictureList.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
}
```

And I have another file `util.js` in witch I am calling `showPicturesList()` function

```
window.onload = function(){
    showPictureList();
}
```

Simply using js I would import both scripts into my html, but with webpack I can make one file for both of them so `webpack.config.js` I added both of these files as `entry` array.
My output file `bundle.js` looks as it should it has both of those files inside of it. The question is what would be the easiest way with minimal changes on js files to call `showPictureList()` function from `utils.js` file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ES2015/ES6 modules to import your functions which have been exported in another file. In your `showPictures.js` file you export the functions you want to expose, by adding the `export` keyword.

```
export function showPicturesList() {
    if (!isEmpty($('#picture-name-list'))) {
        var pictureList = document.getElementById("added-pictures");
        pictureList.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
}
```

And then you need to import them in your `util.js`.

```
import { showPicturesList } from './showPictures';
```

For detailed informations on how to use modules you can have a look at [Exploring JS: Modules](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html).

With this you also don't need to add both files to `entry` in your webpack config, because webpack will see the imports and include eveything you're importing.

Comment: And what about using this function in html? Would that work also or not?

Comment: No it doesn't. You would need to expose it either in your webpack config or by defining it on `window`. Look at this question for details: [Calling webpacked code from outside (HTML script tag)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357489/calling-webpacked-code-from-outside-html-script-tag)