# Webpack 2: Expose variable to global context, and use it in same project

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, webpack-2

I'm trying to expose an object to the global context using Webpack 2 and TypeScript. This variable needs to be globally accessible because it's going to receive commands and attributes from an external script, so it cannot be existing in its enclosed context.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357489/calling-webpacked-code-from-outside-html-script-tag), which taught me how to output one bundle via the [`output.library`](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/output/#output-library) configuration.

**Here is my webpack.config file:**

```
entry:{
    fluxCapacitor: "./ts/main/fluxCapacitor.ts",
    control: "./ts/control/index.ts"
},

output:{
    path: __dirname + "/js",
    filename: "[name].js",
    library: "[name]",
    libraryTarget: "var"
},
```

**fluxCapacitor.ts file:**

```
export default class Core{
    constructor(){
        console.log("Need more jiggawatts");
    }
}
```

**control/index.ts file:**

```
var myFlux = new (<any>window).fluxCapacitor.default();
```

The problem I have now is that the `fluxCapacitor` class is available globally, but the instance `myFlux` is not. Now `myFlux` is trapped in the control context, and I cannot reach it using the browser console.

I also tried adding the variable to the `window` object, but TypeScript simply won't let me:

```
window.myFlux = new (<any>window).fluxCapacitor.default();
// property 'myFlux' does not exist on type 'Window'
```

**Question:**

What is the easiest/simplest way to expose a variable to the global scope, out of Webpack's bundled context?

Answer (score 1):

For a class instance, just do the same thing you're doing for the class -- export it:

**myFlux.ts**

```
import fluxCapacitor from './fluxCapacitor';

export default fluxCapacitor.default();
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
entry:{
    ...
    myFlux: "./ts/main/myFlux.ts",
    ...
},
```

and `myFlux` will end up on the `window` object.