# Bootstrapping Angular CLI App with HTML script tag

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an Angular 4 app which is using `SystemJS`. I want to move to using `Angular CLI`. The problem is, I bootstrap the application in the `index.html` using a script tag as follows.

```
<script>
    var sf = $.ServicesFramework([ModuleContext:ModuleId]);
    System.import('app/main.js')
        .then(module => module.main(sf.getModuleId(), sf.getTabId(), sf.getAntiForgeryValue())
        .catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });

</script>
```

Here is the relevant code from my `main.ts`

```
export function main(dnnModuleId: number, dnnTabId: number, dnnAntiForgeryToken: string) {

     let appConfig: IAppConfig = {
         DNN_MODULE_ID: dnnModuleId
         ...
      }

 platformBrowserDynamic([
     {provide: APP_CONFIG_TOKEN, useValue: appconfig
     ...
 ]).bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

After an extensive search, I i was only able to find an old [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357489/calling-webpacked-code-from-outside-html-script-tag) related to Webpack 1 and not related to `Angular CLI`.

In short is it possible to do this with Angular CLI?

If so, any guidance in where to begin looking would be much appreciated.

Comment: what does `module.main` do?

Comment: @Maximus I think it just runs `platform.bootstrap` with some configuration

Comment: Angular-cli doesn't have `library` option AFAIK https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/%40angular/cli/models/webpack-configs/common.ts#L77-L82 So you can use `window` object

Comment: @yurzui You are correct. I will update the answer with my `main` code. In the meantime, are you saying assign my `main` function in typescript to something like `window.UniqueLoaderName`, and then call that from a `script` tag in `index.html`?

Comment: Inside index.html write `var sf = $.ServicesFramework([ModuleContext:ModuleId]);
        window.FrameworkConfig = {
            moduleId: sf.getModuleId(),
            tabId: sf.getTabId(),
            antiForgeryValue: sf.getAntiForgeryValue()
        };` and use it inside `main.ts` You do not need `main` function anymore

Comment: If you are going to get data asynchnously then you can create some function within `index.html` and call it inside `main.ts`