# How to access Javascript in a completely separate webpacked app

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm working on an existing large client side web app, transpiled with Babel and Webpacked.

I'm writing a separate small project that needs to tap into the existing code, but without access to it in the local filesystem. This is a Node/web app that will work as a test harness to allow remote developers to create assets that interface with our app. What I need to do is be able to import and use any JS classes that the main app exports / uses, without having that code on the local filesystem.

The answers to this question point to using the library option in the output section of webpack config:
[Calling webpacked code from outside (HTML script tag)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357489/calling-webpacked-code-from-outside-html-script-tag)

I've used the suggestion below the main answer for multiple entry points in one of the comments, eg:
"We have multiple entry points, so in the output section, I instead made it library: ["GlobalAccess", "[name]"],. That then make the var be an object with members for each entrypoint: GlobalAccess.EntryPointFoo, GlobalAccess.EntryPointBar, etc"

My output section looks like this:

```
output: {
    // the name of the output file (i.e. same as the input file)
    path: './',
    library: ['GlobalAccess', '[name]'],
    filename: '[name].js'
}
```

However, after doing a build, the output chunks from Webpack are exactly the same as without this option. There are no occurrences of 'GlobalAccess' in any files produced. What should I see in the output chunks that tells me its worked?? The official documentation is pretty sparse..
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-library
but this example shows how to set a library up so every entry has a different namespace:
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multi-part-library

Answer (score 0):

Well, in case anyone else ever comes across this question, which admittedly is a bit of a strange one, I did the following:

> Convert the Webpack build to a library, with 'umd' as the library target
>
> Upgrade Webpack from v1.14 to v2.x in order to use export default class instead of just module.exports
>
> Turn off Uglification and Chunking

So that meant I could have a big project compiled in one place using Webpack, and the resulting output file can be imported and used in a completely different project without access to the original.