# How do I use google maps async callback with knockout and webpack?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, knockout.js, webpack, asynccallback

Hi all. I'm trying to integrate google maps api with knockout and webpack. I've set my request for the google maps api directly in my html. The script includes a callback function that I want to execute once its finished loading. But when I run the server I get the error "initMap is not a function." I think this is happening because the function is located in a bundle but I'm not sure. Does anybody know why this is happening? 

Heres the js that I'm bundling:

```
import ko from 'knockout';


function initMap() {
  console.log('hey')
}


var MyApp = () => {
}


ko.applyBindings(new MyApp())
```

Heres the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Neighborhood Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/main.css"
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map">
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="build/bundle.js"></script>
    <script defer
      src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=[KEY]&v=3&callback=initMap">
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Here's my webpack config file:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'sourcemap',
      entry: './app.js',
      output: {
        path: path.resolve('build', ''),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
      },
      module: {
      noParse: /node_modules\/knockout\/build\/output\/*.js/,
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html-loader'
        },
          {
            test: /\.js?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015']
            }
          },
        ]
    }
};
```

FYI I've tried putting the initMap funtion in MyApp variable as well as leaving as seen as a global function. Neither option works. Do you think I should request the script within the js file instead as a script in the html? If so, what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After days of scouring the internet I finally found the answer here: [Calling webpacked code from outside (HTML script tag)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357489/calling-webpacked-code-from-outside-html-script-tag)

The answer I used is actually the 3rd accepted answer. It involves setting the function as a property of the window and exporting the function

```
window.initMap = initMap
export function initMap() { function stuff }
```

Please, if this answer helps you, go to that site and upvote that answer so it becomes the accepted answer.