# Setting WebPack & Babel to use ES6 modules but gets Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, webpack, build, babeljs

I'm just getting started with Webpack & Babel to take advantage of exporting ES6's modules.

My build setup generates `build/main.build.js` used in `index.html` but browser console shows error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: calculateInterest is not defined`

As, I'm new to this, I'm not sure where the problem actually lies, is it in the my `webpack.config.js` or `package.json` setup or the exporting and importing modules or in the compiled `build/main.build.js`.

Can anybuddy help me get this setup right. Here are the build files.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "learn-webpack",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A shot at learning WebPack",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "http-server",
    "webpack": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "webpack",
    "learn-webpack"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.16.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "http-server": "^0.11.1",
    "webpack": "^4.16.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

**Webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path') 

module.exports = {
    entry: './scripts/main.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'main.bundle.js'
    },

    module: {
         rules: [
             {
                 test: /\.js$/,
                 use: [{
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    query: {
                         presets: ['es2015']
                    }
                 }]
             }
         ]
     },
     optimization: {
        minimize: false
     },

     mode: 'development',

     stats: {
         colors: true
     }
 };
```

**Index.html**

```
<head>
    <title>Babel Learning</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="build/main.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>
<body onload="init()">

    <button id="btn">Calculate Interest</button>

    <div id="result"></div>

<script>
    function init() {
        var btn = document.getElementById('btn')
        var result = document.getElementById('result')


        btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
            var interest = calculateInterest(3000,29,1)
            result.innerHTML = interest
        })
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**scripts/main.js**

```
import getSI from './js/getSI.js'
```

**scripts/js/getSI.js**

```
export function calculateInterest(principal, rate, time) {
    var interest = (principal * rate * time) / 100
    return interest
}
```

Thanks for your help. Much appreciated.

appu

Answer (score 0):

You can export the functions you want to from `main.js`:

```
  import { calculateInterest } from './js/getSI.js';
  export { calculateInterest };
```

and change your `webpack` output settings to

```
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'main.bundle.js',
    libraryTarget: 'this',
    library: 'LearnWebpack'
  },
```

In doing so you will get `LearnWebpack` available in browser

```
  <script>
  function init() {
    var btn = document.getElementById('btn')
    var result = document.getElementById('result')
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var interest = LearnWebpack.calculateInterest(3000, 29, 1)
      result.innerHTML = interest
    })
  }
  </script>
```

[Here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#expose-via-object-assignment) you can find details about `webpack`'s `libraryTarget` available settings. From what I know these settings ([library](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-library)) are for libraries but it should get your experiments going.

I found a similar issue in [this older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357489/calling-webpacked-code-from-outside-html-script-tag) - same idea but the used settings are for webpack@2 (I think)
Hope it helps

Comment: hi, ur suggestions did not work for me. Have u tried with my setup (files) at your end?

Comment: I did try it. 
Sorry to hear it is not working for you. Are you getting the same error or a new one?

Comment: I get `Uncaught TypeError: LearnWebpack.calculateInterest is not a function`