# Multiple background scripts not supported in compiled chrome extension

Tags: javascript, webpack, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to share functions across multiple backgrounds scripts in a chrome-extension. This works easily / by design in general as long as you add the scripts to the manifest.json, then a function called from the background.js can call code in another script as long as that other script is loaded first.

HOWEVER, I've tried a few Chrome extension generator templates that have a compilation step with gulp or webpack. (e.g. This one: https://github.com/samuelsimoes/chrome-extension-webpack-boilerplate)

**But unfortunately function sharing breaks in the compiled background.js scripts**.

I don't know what "magic" in the chrome-extension architecture is broken when compiled code is used.

Any advice/insights on what could be preventing function sharing appreciated.
For details on the implementation e.g. webpack.config etc. please see the boilerplate as that's what I'm working with as well.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with that boilerplate because the ability to use multiple scripts in one page is not magic, it's a basic ability of any DOM-based page such as the extension background page, and it should just work. I guess that boilerplate doesn't want you to share the functions, it wants you to use modules either via `require()` or ES-modules.

Comment: Still researching but i think it might be due to what webpack does as part of the bundling process as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357489/calling-webpacked-code-from-outside-html-script-tag

Comment: Also, discovered that if i reveal all the functions using module.exports = { functionA: function A} etc. in the shared script, i can use these functions using require. Previously i wasn't exporting the functions (and didn't need to when webpack was not in use) but I guess this could be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question after some further research:

The issue appeared to be that webpack compiled each file into a module, necessitating changes to accomodate function sharing between these files.

Rather than adding module.exports statements to each background script, and having to prefix all my function references with the module name, I decided it was easier to rely on webpack (specifically the webpack-concat-plugin) to concat the background files together.