# Access variable in webpack bundled javascript file, from an html script tag (inline)

Tags: javascript, webpack

This has been answered before, but I have a peculiar problem.

I have a function

```
function foo() { 
    return 'bar';
}
```

in an app.js file I bundled with webpack.

Now I need to access this function from a script tag inside a html file.
I tried to bind the function to the global window object, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46493610/4625623), and it seemed to work.

Problem now is that other variables from plugins that I use on the same page, (which used to work fine) are now "not defined".

For example `grecaptcha.execute();` now throws

> grecaptcha is not defined

Could someone please suggest a way around this.
I'd really appreciate an explanation to understand what is going on.