# How to call a function in webpacked code (bundle.js) from angular component?

Tags: angular, webpack

I m trying to call a function in webpacked library (bundle.js) from an angular component. I used this [anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34361312/10682411) to bundle my library and was able to call the function from an index.html file using the code from the answer. I also included the bundled js library in my angular project and now i would like to call it from somewhere in angular, like from a component.

So far i tried to declare my library in an angular component like this

```
declare const the_library: any;
```

then use it from somewhere in component like this

```
the_library.method1();
```

but i m getting error : ERROR ReferenceErro the_library is not defined

Comment: In config, do you have `library: 'the_library'`? If you opened the developer tools and typed in the console `the_library.method1()`, will it run the desired function?

Comment: thanx,  the solution......  i included my bundle.js in angular.clis styles array instead of scripts array *facepam*.  What a solution. lol.