# How to expose a single entry point bundle as a library in webpack configuration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a webpack.config.js file defined as `module.exports = function (env, args)` with different entry points. Now I want to add an entry point and expose it as a library. [Calling webpacked code from outside (HTML script tag)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357489/calling-webpacked-code-from-outside-html-script-tag) says we can do

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: './lib',
    filename: 'yourlib.js',
    libraryTarget: 'var',
    library: 'EntryPoint'
  }
};
```

But how do I restrict this to a specific entry point.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention the webpack version you are using. With version `5.75.0` you can achieve that with the following config. I am assuming 2 entry points in the example:

```js
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './index.js',
    lib: {
      filename: '[name].js',
      import: './lib/yourlib.js',
      library: {
        name: 'YourLibName',
        type: 'umd',
      },
    }
  },
  output: {
    path: './dist',
    filename: '[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  }
};
```

You can refer to [webpack's documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrary) to explore the parameters available to configure library options per entry point.

With older versions of webpack you will have to create a separate `webpack.config` file to generate your library bundle.